# Search brings up completely unrelated items

Tags: search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, magento2.4.3

When typing in search terms and the search brings up products unrelated in both name and meta-keywords.

This happens only with actual words though, typing in incoherent strings of letters does not bring up any search results.

What could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

First check how many and which attributes are set to be used for search. To check this:

- Go to **Stores** > **Attributes** > **Product**
- Filter attributes based on **Searchable** = **YES**

Analyse and try to reduce the number of attributes being used for search.

**Logic supporting above:** Suppose you have description attribute set as searchable, then each word in the description will be treated as an individual keyword for search, even though you don't want it.

So try to use only those attributes enabled for search which you think are necessary.

Once you are done with reducing number of attributes from being searchable, do a reindex for EAV and CatalogSearch.

Hope this helps.